# iOS link background colour changes when scrolling

Tags: ios, css

On my website I have a list of products wrapped in a `a` link with `display:block` so the whole product and its details are clickable.

The `a` link doesnt have a `hover` `background-colour` but it has an `active` `background-colour` so the bg colour changes someone clicks on the link..

The problem I have is on my iPhone, when I scroll, the `a` link's background colour changes to the `active` state's bg colour. Its very annoying when items background colour changes while scrolling through the products. Why is that? Whats the best way to stop it from happening and still change the `background-colour` once clicked on iOS? Am I the ONLY one who got this problem??

Please let me know if you need a jsfiddle. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done it in my app is to explicitly mention all the states so there is no ambiguity. My CSS kinda looks like this -

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #ffcc99;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}

a:hover   { //technically not required to mention hover
    color:black;
}

a:active  {
    color:grey;

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. Works better. But when I tap, the whole `a` link's background colour changes and I cant the product details if you know what I mean. The whole block gets filled with the colour. Am I doing somethng wrong?

Comment: why dont you explicitly set the `background` to each of the 4 different states of `a` tag in your CSS? See if it still happens..